# How would you translate "as having" to Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do you say "as having" in Spanish, as in the following sentence?

> The regions were the first to be approved by Parliament as having independent status.

I looked it up on SpanishDict and found "como tener" but doubted it could be as simple and literal as that.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion that sentence has a passive structure that does not exists in Spanish, where the indirect object becomes the subject*. So, in that context *as having* does not have an immediate translation. Instead, I would rewrite the sentence completely in order to make some sense of it.

My guess (without context I'm afraid it does not have much sense):

> Las regiones fueron las primeras a las que el Parlamento otorgó
>   estatus de independencia.

My second guess (imagining the context, some creative work here =D):

> Las autonomías fueron las primeras a las que el Congreso otorgó estatutos independientes.

In any case, what is clear is that "as having" implies **possession** or **acquisition**.

*In active voice, it would be something like:

> The Parliament approves indepent status for the regions.

Where the O.D. is "independent status" and the O.I. is "the regions", which becomes the subject in this passive form.

Comment: Maybe the best Spanish verb here would be *reconocer*, but I agree with the general idea.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that there are more options besides what I proposed, I guess it depends on the context (which is not very clear for me).

Comment: A closer active version of the original sentence would be “The regions were the first which Parliament approved as having independent status” (though I think _recognised_ would fit better in English than _approved_ as well).

Comment: I don't think this is really correct in English, either. It's one of those situations where the literal meaning is nonsensical, but one's brain automatically infers the correct meaning. It should be "The regions were the first to have their independent status approved by Parliament."

Answer (score 5):

Alicia explained *why* better than I could, so I'll just give my take on the translation:

> Las regiones fueron las primeras en ser aprobadas por el Parlamento ***como poseedoras de*** estatus independiente.
>   Las regiones fueron las primeras en ser aprobadas por el Parlamento ***para tener*** estatus independiente.

This avoids having to reword the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually even simpler.  You'd want to use *en tener* instead of *como tener*.

Manteniendo más o menos la estructura (que no haría en una traducción normal), la frase la traduciría como:

> Las regiones fueron las primeras que el Parlamento aprobó para tener estatus independiente.

Comment: @walen concuerdo.  Manteniendo más o menos la estructura (que no haría en una traducción normal), la frase la traduciría como «Las regiones fueron las primeras que el Parlamento aprobó para tener estatus independiente»

Comment: @guifa esta información debería estar en tu respuesta - para agregar mas contenido a la misma.

Answer (score 1):

Se podría usar la palabra ***habiente*** para describir el sujeto de tu enunciado como tal:

> Las regiones fueron las primeras en ser aprobadas por el Parlamento como ***habientes*** de estatus independiente.

Según el diccionario de la Real Academia Española:

> [***habiente***](http://dle.rae.es/?w=habiente)
>
> Del ant. part. act. de haber, 1.
>
> 1. adj. Que tiene. U. t. c. s.(Usado también como sustantivo) y especialmente en expresiones jurídicas, unas veces antepuesto y otras pospuesto al nombre que es su complemento. Habiente o habientes derecho, o derecho habiente o habientes.

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta psosuna! De todos modos en España sonaría basante raro y seguramente se asociaría con el habla de un jurista con la toga puesta :) Bienvenido a [spanish.se]

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por la bienvenida amable. Definitivamente conlleva un aire de leyes. De cualquier modo, como se discute un estatus legal de independencia no estaría tan mal acertado que llegara a ser usado en algún contexto de noticias o en una corte de justicia.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [walen's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22623/1674) in that **para tener** could be a good option, but I would rephrase it entirely to translate the complex sentence:

> The regions were the first to be approved by Parliament as having independent status.

Into something that is more straight forward like:

> Las regiones fueron las primeras **a las que el Parlamento dio** estatus independiente.

Which sounds more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate it as:

> Las regiones fueron las primeras cuyo estado independiente fue aprobado por el congreso.

Comment: Hola CESAR, ¿podrías añadir alguna explicación a tu respuesta para hacerla más útil? Lee [answer] como referencia, ¡gracias!

Answer (score -1):

A mi parecer como hablante nativo, la frase `The regions were the first to be approved by Parliament as having independent status` puede traducirse de varias maneras:

1.- `Las regiones fueron las primeras en ser aprobadas por el parlamento teniendo estatus independiente` la cual me parece la opción más aceptable y correcta, de hecho la traducción literal sería `como teniendo`, pero en español esa construcción no existe, se dice simplemente `teniendo`.

2.- `Las regiones fueron las primeras en ser aprobadas por el parlamento considerandolas con estatus independiente` si la traduccion de `as having` se relaciona con una entidad que tiene capacidad de razonar, como en este caso el `parlamento`.

3.- `Las regiones fueron las primeras en ser aprobadas por el parlamento, el cual las consideró con estatus independiente` con la misma explicación que la anterior.

4.- `Las regiones fueron las primeras en ser aprobadas por el parlamento como si tuvieran estatus independiente` puede ser una opción, sin embargo en esta ocasión `como si tuvieran` da la idea de que en realidad las regiones no tienen estatus independiente, sino de que alguien así lo considera, pero no lo tienen.

5.- `Las regiones fueron las primeras en ser aprobadas por el parlamento como que tenían estatus independiente` da una idea semejante a la anterior pero menos acentuada.